# How does one create a div that uses iconCls to draw icons?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

How can I generate a div that uses iconCls to populate the equivalent of an icon as that div's content?

Eg

```
{
xtype:button,
iconCls: 'refresh',
iconMask: true,
}
```

Will generate a button with the refresh icon. As far as I know, Ext & Sencha generate that from CSS though, so it should surely be possible to call the right class on a div and have it automagically draw the refresh icon for me?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sencha doesn't automatically draws and icon with whatever name you give. It may work only when sencha has already added an iconCls with that image. However, you can yourself add an iconCls and add that class to your css.

so, for you, the css will be like this:

```
.refresh{
    background : url('your image location');
    height : 16px;  // Height-width of the image
    width : 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also recently created this that will help you to prepare icons for your Sencha Touch apps.  The README explains the steps for creating icons at the Ico Moon web site and using the tool to convert Ico Moon project files into SCSS for use in Sencha Touch.

- https://github.com/tohagan/sencha-ico-moon